# Kusto: Query properties within stringified JSON body

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Using Kusto Query Language, Is it possible to parse a stringified JSON body and then filter by value for a specific key within this JSON body?

For example, a `data` blob contains a string property `message`.

Within this `message`, it contains a stringified JSON body.

Within this stringified JSON body, kusto query results by `"provider"`.

Example `message` with stringified JSON body:

```
message: "app profile: {\"appId\":\"7cf1b9f9\",\"provider\":\"sharepoint\",\"updatedAt\":\"2022-11-08T19:26:40Z\"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you could use the [`parse` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseoperator).

For example:

```
datatable(input: string)
[
    'app profile: {\"appId\":\"7cf1b9f9\",\"provider\":\"sharepoint\",\"updatedAt\":\"2022-11-08T19:26:40Z\"}',
    'app profile: {\"appId\":\"7cf1b9f9\",\"provider\":\"kusto\",\"updatedAt\":\"2022-11-08T19:26:40Z\"}',
]
| parse input with 'app profile: ' payload:dynamic
| where payload.provider == 'kusto'
```

| input | payload |
| --- | --- |
| app profile: {"appId":"7cf1b9f9","provider":"kusto","updatedAt":"2022-11-08T19:26:40Z"} | { "appId": "7cf1b9f9", "provider": "kusto", "updatedAt": "2022-11-08T19:26:40Z" } |